# Android app crashes when trying to append received message from USB

Tags: android, communication, nano

So when I try to append a string to my textview gotten from my callback function, the app crashes.
I'm sending a message from arduino nano to my android and I can see the message on serial monitor in Ardunio IDE but when I connect the arduino to my Android through a OTG cable it just crashes.
If you need more information about the code or error messages, please let me know. I dont know what to look for.

The crashing happens if I uncomment the commented line below.

```
private var mCallback = UsbReadCallback { data: ByteArray? ->
    Log.i("Serial", "Data received: ${data.toString()}")
    val dataStr = data.toString()
    val textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txRead)
    // textview.append(dataStr)
}
```

And this is the logcat when the commented line is uncommented, just as the message got received.

```
01-18 23:06:52.244 32733   342 I Serial  : Data received: [B@15e7ea4
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.thirdattempt, PID: 32733
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7361)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5261)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13708)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13643)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13627)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7667)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4585)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4442)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:4139)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:4129)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.example.thirdattempt.MainActivity.mCallback$lambda-5(MainActivity.kt:123)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.example.thirdattempt.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$sDCpzleXwuhQv0Ik07ap_TtZY1w(MainActivity.kt)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.example.thirdattempt.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onReceivedData(Unknown Source)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice$WorkerThread.onReceivedData(UsbSerialDevice.java:391)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice$WorkerThread.doRun(UsbSerialDevice.java:360)
01-18 23:06:52.258 32733   342 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.felhr.usbserial.AbstractWorkerThread.run(AbstractWorkerThread.java:21)
01-18 23:06:52.277  1199  1199 I SendBroadcastPermission: action:android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED, mPermissionType:0
01-18 23:06:52.277   573  1002 I logserver: handle_logfile_events, Object Path:/data/system/dropbox/, mask=0x00000080
01-18 23:06:52.277   573  1002 I logserver: process_one_event, event->len=48, name=data_app_crash@1642518412277.txt
01-18 23:06:52.277   573  1002 I logserver: find_first_match: find match, plogs(type=1, pfile=/data/system/dropbox/, match=app_crash)
01-18 23:06:52.278   573  1002 I iMonitor: create: 901001001
01-18 23:06:52.278   573  1002 I logserver: process_event_by_imonitor, pos=0, type=crash, event_id=901001001
01-18 23:06:52.278   573  1002 I logserver: get_acr_info, match:(app_crash), actual_name:(data_app_crash@1642518412277.txt)
01-18 23:06:52.278   573  1002 E logserver: imonitor_add_dynamic_path, path:/data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1642518412277.txt
01-18 23:06:52.278   573  1002 I iMonitor: send: 901001001
01-18 23:06:52.278   573  1002 I logserver: imonitor_send_event ret=156
01-18 23:06:52.279   573  1003 I logserver: handle_exception_events enter
01-18 23:06:52.286  1199  8620 E ReportTools: This is not beta user build
01-18 23:06:52.288 32733   342 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 32733 SIG: 9
01-18 23:06:52.290  1778  2064 I ash     : com.example.thirdattempt { running duration=2941 } transition to: end, reason:not_running
01-18 23:06:52.290  1778  2064 I ash     : remove app record pkg: com.example.thirdattempt
01-18 23:06:52.292  1199  1212 E Process : isHighLoadProcess: get cpu failed
```

Comment: Well you should post the logcat lines with the exception you did not catch that lets your app crash.  Put the log statement first then you know if the data was ok.

Comment: You can connect your device via Wifi to your PC so that you can use the USB connector and at the same time see the error message on `adb logcat`. Please capture this error message and the stack trace, edit your question and add it formatted as code.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! It should modified as you said now. adb logcat was very helpful.